# In pom.xml can we keep maven-compiler-plugin and maven-surefire-plugin under a dependency tag instead of plugin tag?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, pom.xml

While Creating a maven project for Selenium I generally keep
maven-compiler-plugin and maven-surefire-plugin under plugin tag as
follows:

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-beta-4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

But I saw in maven central repo following dependency for them

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    </dependency>
```

So can we keep these as a dependency instead of plugin?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What is the purpose of it? A plugin is never a dependency of a project. It's a plugin..which means to be defined in pluginManagement instead.

Answer (score 2):

maven central repo. is only showing you groupId, artifactId and version of it. But in your case, you have to use them in build and provide configurations. So, in short answer to your question is **No**.

dependency tag is only to declare dependencies but plugin has much more work to do in projects build. For details refer to https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugins.html

Comment: So in no case maven-compiler dependency will be used, It will "always" be used as a plugin, right?